# Django-сервер не отдает static файлы

Tags: django, static-content

Сервер не отдает css файлы для странички администратора(127.0.0.1/admin). Причем только когда в settings.py отключен debug-режим(переменная DEBUG выставлена false). Когда отладка включена все работает. При попытке запросить http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/base.css выдает ошибку 404, хотя такой файл лежит по этому пути. STATIC_ROOT я настраивал и collectstatic тоже делал, но не помогло.
Содержимое settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for homeSite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secret)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'homeSite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'homeSite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Дерево каталогов относительно папки проекта(там где лежит manage.py)

```
.
├── homeSite
│   └── __pycache__
└── static
    ├── admin
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── vendor
    │   │       └── select2
    │   ├── fonts
    │   ├── img
    │   │   └── gis
    │   └── js
    │       ├── admin
    │       └── vendor
    │           ├── jquery
    │           ├── select2
    │           │   └── i18n
    │           └── xregexp
    └── vendor
        └── select2
```

Comment: Вы небось запускаете проект с помощью `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, а что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files):

> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually
>   serve the static files.
>
> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will
>   be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see
>   django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
>
> This method is **grossly inefficient** and **probably insecure**, so it is
>   **unsuitable for production**.
>
> See [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/) for proper strategies to serve static files
>   in production environments.

По-русски говоря, `runserver` должен использоваться только для разработки и тестирования, его нельзя использовать в бою. А механизм отдачи статики настолько ресурсоёмкий и небезопасный, что Django вообще отключает его, если `DEBUG` установлен в `False`.

Настройте Nginx на обслуживание статики на боевом сервере.

Answer (score 0):

По команде collectstatic ваша статика из вашего проекта и из сторонних библиотек копируется в STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

И потом вы настраиваете nginx на папку STATIC_ROOT, так у вас в боевом режиме будет отдаваться статика.